# Inner join and 2 left joins

Tags: sql, netezza

The inner join works, **i can** left join the second table, but i **cant** join the third table.

I dont know why, even if i inner join the first table and then left join the third it doenst work.

If i inner join the table and left join with the second it works like said, but when i put the third table into the query it fails again.

```
create table xxxx AS select 
t1.XXX,
t2.YYY,
t3.ZZZ 
from 
DB_AA..P1 t1
INNER JOIN DB_TT..TQ t5 on (t5.NR = t1.NR)
LEFT JOIN DB_II..GG t2 ON (t2.LS = t1.LS)
LEFT JOIN DB_AA..PP t3 ON (t3.NR= t1.NR)
```

Anybody see something i dont see?
I pass the code to a Netezza.

Comment: Do you get an error?  What is the specific problem?  *can't* is a little bit on the vague side.

Comment: I don´t get it...now it work´s.
The same code as yesterday, strange.

Comment: Nothing bad with a bit of good karma. Please let us know if you need more of that from us, or perhaps replicate the issue :)